# Does MvcSiteMapProvider support "Sql Server" session state?

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to use the MvcSiteMapProvider in an application that is configured with *SqlServer* session state mode.
However, I get an exception the moment I call the *RegisterRoutes* method of *XmlSiteMapController* class, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // ...
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

    // Add our route registration for MvcSiteMapProvider sitemaps
    MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Mvc.XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes(routes);
}
```

Then I get an exception saying

> *Type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.*

This makes me think MvcSiteMapProvider does not support SqlServer session state mode. Does it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have customized it, `MvcSiteMapProvider` does not interact with session state in any way. So, it should work with any mode of session state (I haven't tested it with SqlServer mode, so if you continue having issues I suggest you open a [new issue](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/new) about it). Please see [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) for an explanation about how it works without session state.

The error posted indicates your application is trying to serialize the `System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary`, which is not something that `MvcSiteMapProvider` does.

On a side note, you don't need to call `XmlSiteMapController.RegisterRoutes` explicitly from an MVC 4 application as long as you have installed the `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4` NuGet package. This method is called automatically using [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator). It is possible you might be having issues by calling it twice.

Comment: Hi! Indeed, it had nothing to do with MvcSiteMapProvider. Sorry for that. It might be another component trying to save its things in session. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

`MvcSiteMapProvider` would need to interact with state servers if you want to put a node into session state for any reason. I do that to keep track of objects that I have associated with the nodes, since `MvcSiteMapProvider` forgets any state information upon each new request.

If you download the code you can add the project to your solution.

If you do a replace and

Replace `public class` with `[System.Serializable]\r\n\public class`

Also replace `public abstract class` with `[System.Serializable]\r\n\public abstract class`

The remove the attribute off the `JavaScriptSerializerAdapter` class.

then it will be usable with State Servers.